# Bash script start docker container script & pass in arguments

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that runs command line functions, and I then need the script to run commands in a docker container. I then need the script to pass in arguments into the docker, and eventually exit. However, I'm unable to have the script pass in arguments into the docker container. How can I do this?

This is what the docker commands look like without the bash script for reference.

```
$ docker exec -it rti_cmd
root@29c:/data# rti
187.0.0.1:9806> run_cmd
(integer) 0
187.0.0.1:9806> exit
root@29c:/data# exit
exit
```

Code snippet with two variations of attempts:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker exec -it rti_cmd bash<< eeee
rti
run_cmd
exit
exit
eeee

#also have done without the ";"
docker exec -it rti_cmd bash /bin/sh -c
"rti;
run_cmd;
exit;
exit"
```

Errors:

```
$ chmod +x test.sh
$ ./test.sh
the input device is not a TTY
/bin/sh: /bin/sh: cannot execute binary file
./test.sh: line 17: $'rti;\nrun_cmd;\nexit;\nexit': command not found
```

Comment: `bash /bin/sh`? Eh? `bash -c` makes sense. `sh -c` makes sense. `bash /bin/sh -c` does not make sense, because `sh` is not a script that `bash` can interpret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `-i` interacive nor `-t` tty if you want to be non-interactive.

```
docker exec rti_cmd sh -c 'rti;run_cmd'
```

Comment: My "run_cmd" is technically a "del something something" command, and I'm getting an error that "del" command doesn't exist when it works outside the script. I assume I need to pass in the del command separately, but doing a separate or nested ```bash -c  "del something something"```  after the rti command doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `del`? Run interactive shell and `type del`.